# Approximating $\int_0^1 x\sin xdx$

Tags: calculus, approximation

Check whether $$\int_0^1 x\sin xdx>0.3$$

---

The anti-derivative of $x\sin x$ is $\sin x-x\cos x$

So the integral is $$I\approx\sin(57^\circ)-\cos(57^\circ)$$

Since $\sin x $ is increasing in the first quadrant and $\cos x$ is decreasing,

$$I<\sin(60^\circ)-\cos(60^\circ)$$

$$I<\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}$$

$$I<0.37$$

Which also means $$I>0.3$$

Is there any other, preferably graphical, method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With $\sin x>x-\frac {x^3}{3!}$, we have:
\begin{align}
\int _0^1x\sin x \, dx&>\int _0^1x^2-\frac {x^4}{6}\, dx\\
&=\big[\frac {x^3}3-\frac {x^5}{30}\big]_0^1\\
&=0.3
\end{align}

Comment: For $x\in(0,1)$, if $f(x)>t$, don't we have $xf(x)<t$?

Comment: We are using $xf(x)>xt$

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Excellent answer anyway!

Answer (score 2):

$I < 0.37$ does not necesarrily imply that $I > 0.3$. By Taylor series again, you would have:

$$I = \sin 1 - \cos 1 \approx 1 - \frac{1^3}{3!} + \frac{1^5}{5!} - \frac{1^7}{7!} - \left(1 - \frac{1^2}{2!} + \frac{1^4}{4!} - \frac{1^6}{6!}\right) = \frac{253}{840} \approx 0.3012.$$

and the maximum error of a Taylor series is given by the next term:

$$\text{Maximum error} = \left|\frac{1}{9!}\right| + \left|\frac{1}{8!}\right| = \frac{1}{36288}$$

but $\frac{253}{840} - \frac{1}{36288} > 0.3$. Hence $\sin 1 - \cos 1 = \int_0^1 x \sin x \ dx > 0.3$.

The series approximation gives $0.3011629 \cdots$, where the actual value of $\sin 1 - \cos 1$ is $0.3011687 \cdots$, off by only $6 \cdot 10^{-6}$.

Comment: Indeed. I realised how stupid that was the next instant I posted it. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: No worries, and thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is a Taylor series around $\frac \pi 3$. This gives
$$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) \sin \left(n\frac{\pi 
   }{2}\right)+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \cos \left(n\frac{\pi  }{2}\right)}{2 n!}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^n$$
$$\sin(1)-\cos(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) \sin \left(n\frac{\pi 
   }{2}\right)+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \cos \left(n\frac{\pi  }{2}\right)}{2 n!}\left(1-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^n$$

Computing the partial sum from $n=0$ to $n=p$, you have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 0 & 0.366025 \\
 1 & 0.301552 \\
 2 & 0.301145 \\
 3 & 0.301169
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I have never seen $\sin x -\cos x$ in this form before! Any reference?

Comment: @DatBoi. This is the Taylor series around $x=\frac \pi 3$

Comment: Ah! I got it. Thank you so much for the help! Taylor expansion around $\pi/3$ makes so much sense!!